# Python: Algorithm to renumbering footnotes in a page (file) of text

Tags: python, algorithm, string-matching

Suppose you have text files, each of which contain text for pages in a book.  Suppose there are from 0 to 10 footnotes per page - and that they are numbered 1 through N for all pages in a chapter.   Now, suppose the last page of a chapter in the book will also overlaps with the first page of the next chapter.

Footnotes are declared with syntax:  (1)  in the text of the pages.

It's the overlapping pages that are giving me fits in re-numbering footnotes per page.  I am wanting each page to have footnotes from 1 to N for that page.

Here is an example of a special case that is problematic for all the loops I've come up with:

Sample Original Page Text:

```
A footnote from the last part of a chapter might begin with any number footnote(2).  
This might be in the last paragraph of some chapter that is ending.

Some Next Chapter DD

A single line(1) of text might have multiple footnotes(2) in it on the same line.
Then a new line of text has another footnote(3) in it.
```

I want to renumber the footnotes for the sample page above, to produce the sample page below:

Desire Footnotes Renumbered Page:
----- sample page of text with footnotes begin -----

```
A footnote from the last part of a chapter might begin with any number footnote(1).  
This might be in the last paragraph of some chapter that is ending. 

Some Next Chapter DD

A single line(2) of text might have multiple footnotes(3) in it on the same line.
Then a new line of text has another footnote(4) in it.
```

With Python, I have not found any looping algorithm that works - whether you make corrections on the file immediately, or buffer the corrections - the next pass of the loop may correctly renumber the right footnote, or may mess up an already corrected footnote from a previous loop pass.  Do I need to use a file seek operation, or can some kind of regex loop handle this ?

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution now for this problem.  Turns out that inline changes can sometime cause two identical footnotes to happen on the same line where the second identical one is the next one to be changed.  Using regex will hit the first one that was previously changed.  A little care is needed to handle this case.

For the code below, `page` is a list of the text lines from file_handle.readlines()

```py
def replace_nth_substring_in_string(string, old, new, nth):
    split_location = [m.start() for m in re.finditer(old, string)][nth - 1]
    (head, tail) = (string[:split_location], string[split_location:])
    tail = tail.replace(old, new, 1)
    return head + tail


new_num = 1
for i in range(len(page)):
    footnote_matches = re.findall( '\(\d+\)', page[i] )
    for nth, match in enumerate( footnote_matches, start=1):
        old = match
        new = '({})'.format(new_num)

        # grabbing this piece of info is key !
        num_old_foots_on_line = page[i].count( old ) 

        # normal case; simple replace
        if num_old_foots_on_line == 1:
            page[i] = page[i].replace( old, new, nth )

        # if a previous correction has now caused two idential footnotes
        # then replace the last one only ...
        elif num_old_foots_on_line == 2:
            page[i] = replace_nth_substring_in_string(page[i], old, new, 1)

        # for my case, there should never be more than three identical
        # but for others, they may have to handle this case
        else:
            print("There are three (or more) footnotes on this line")
            sys.exit()
        new_num+=1
```